# Wpf Application Images not visible when it is part of a dll

Tags: wpf, image

I have two wpf applications. I want to refer dll of App1 inside App2. App1 has a view screen with images(icons mostly). When I add the dll of App1 to App2, the view screen is visible from App2 but the images are not. How can I make the images to be visible from App2. I have set the build action for images as resources in App1.

Comment: not sure, but I think your images are resources of your App1 application and not of your dll, is usefull if you provide a printscreen of your actual settings or solution tree. So far I assume you have to add same images as resources in App2 and dll is only managing the app resources that it finds, not containing them.

Comment: I agree. Sorry I wasn't clear. Is there a way to make images as part of dll so that i need not add them again in App2. This dependency of adding images to App2 whenever there is a change of images in App1 is what i want to avoid.

Comment: Set their Build Action to Resource (as usual), and load them by full [Resource File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris), including the name of the referenced assembly (i.e. the source assembly).

Comment: @Clemens Thank You! It works as expected after I changed the paths using Pack URI's